# What does ^ do in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, what exactly does the

```
    ^
```

operator do?
For example:

```
    select 4 ^ 4;
```

The answer comes out to be zero.
This is same for any two same numbers using this operator;
And it is not number order dependent:

```
    select 5^4;
    select 4^5;
```

have the same answer.

I think the operator depends upon whether the numbers are odd or even.
And also, the behavior for any two single digit numbers is same for any multi digit number with the same unit digit.

So could anyone explain to me what the ^ operator does?

Comment: The answer is seriously in the first result when you google "mysql ^ operator"

Answer (score 5):

Just consult [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-xor). With numerical arguments, the `^` operator does a bit-wise exclusive OR of its arguments. That's why it comes out 0 for any repeated argument: your XOR'ing something with itself.

Note that in some contexts, `^` is a [logical XOR operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor).